# Keeping your statistician happy: Stata vs. R Student's t-test

Tags: r, statistics, stata, data-science

## Chapter 1: mean age by gender

I work a lot with epidemiologists and statisticians that have very specific requirements for their statistical output and I frequently fail to reproduce the exact same thing in R (our epidemiologst works in Stata).

Let's start with an easy example, a Student's t-test. What we are interested in is the difference in mean age at first diagnosis and a confidence interval.

**1) create some sample data in R**

```
set.seed(41)

cohort <- data.frame(
          id = seq(1,100),
          gender = sample(c(rep(1,33), rep(2,67)),100),
          age    = sample(seq(0,50),100, replace=TRUE)
          )

# save to import into Stata
# write.csv(cohort, "cohort.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

**b) import data and run t-test in Stata**

```
import delimited "cohort.csv"
ttest age, by(gender)
```

[image]

What we want is the absolute difference in the mean= 3.67 years and the combined confidence intervals = 95% CI: 24.59 - 30.57

**b) run t-test in R**

```
t.test(age~gender, data=cohort)
```

[image]

```
t.test(cohort$age[cohort$gender == 1])
```

[image]

```
t.test(cohort$age[cohort$gender == 2])
```

[image]

```
t.test(cohort$age)
```

[image]

There surely must be another way instead of running 4 t-tests in R!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What we want is the absolute difference in the mean= 3.67 years and the combined confidence intervals = 95% CI: 24.59 - 30.57

Notice that R's `t.test` does a t-test, whereas you want a mean difference and "combined confidence intervals" (which is CI around the mean ignoring the grouping variable). So you don't want a t-test but something else.

You can get the mean difference using, e.g.:

```
diff(with(cohort, tapply(age, gender, mean)))
# 3.669833 
# no point in using something more complicated e.g., t-test or lm
```

... and the CI using, e.g.:

```
confint(lm(age~1, data=cohort))
#                2.5 %   97.5 %
# (Intercept) 24.58985 30.57015
```

And obviously, you can easily combine the two steps into one function if you need it often.

```
doit <- function(a,b) c(diff= diff(tapply(a,b,mean)), CI=confint(lm(a~1)))
with(cohort, doit(age,gender))
#   diff.2       CI1       CI2 
# 3.669833 24.589853 30.570147
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put everything in one function and some `tidyverse` magic. The output can be edited as your needs are of course. `boom`'s `tidy` will be used for nice output.

```
foo <- function(df, x, y){
  require(tidyverse)
  require(broom)
  a1 <- df %>% 
    select(ep=!!x, gr=!!y) %>% 
    mutate(gr=as.character(gr)) %>% 
    bind_rows(mutate(., gr="ALL")) %>% 
    split(.$gr) %>% 
    map(~tidy(t.test(.$ep))) %>% 
    bind_rows(.,.id = "gr") %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
  tidy(t.test(as.formula(paste(x," ~ ",y)), data=df)) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
    mutate(gr="vs") %>% 
    select(gr, estimate, statistic, p.value,parameter, conf.low, conf.high, method, alternative) %>% 
    bind_rows(a1, .)}


foo(cohort, "age", "gender")
   gr  estimate statistic      p.value parameter  conf.low conf.high                  method alternative
1   1 25.121212  9.545737 6.982763e-11  32.00000  19.76068 30.481745       One Sample t-test   two.sided
2   2 28.791045 15.699854 5.700541e-24  66.00000  25.12966 32.452428       One Sample t-test   two.sided
3 ALL 27.580000 18.301678 1.543834e-33  99.00000  24.58985 30.570147       One Sample t-test   two.sided
4  vs -3.669833 -1.144108 2.568817e-01  63.37702 -10.07895  2.739284 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

I recommend to start from the beginning using this

```
foo <- function(df){
 a1 <- broom::tidy(t.test(age~gender, data=df))
 a2 <- broom::tidy(t.test(df$age))
 a3 <- broom::tidy(t.test(df$age[df$gender == 1]))
 a4 <- broom::tidy(t.test(df$age[df$gender == 2]))
 list(rbind(a2, a3, a4), a1)
}

foo(cohort)
[[1]]
  estimate statistic      p.value parameter conf.low conf.high            method alternative
1 27.58000 18.301678 1.543834e-33        99 24.58985  30.57015 One Sample t-test   two.sided
2 25.12121  9.545737 6.982763e-11        32 19.76068  30.48174 One Sample t-test   two.sided
3 28.79104 15.699854 5.700541e-24        66 25.12966  32.45243 One Sample t-test   two.sided

[[2]]
   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic   p.value parameter  conf.low conf.high                  method alternative
1 -3.669833  25.12121  28.79104 -1.144108 0.2568817  63.37702 -10.07895  2.739284 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own function:

```
tlimits <- function(data, group){
  error <- qt(0.975, df = length(data)-1)*sd(data)/(sqrt(length(data)))
  mean <- mean(data)
  means <- tapply(data, group, mean)
  c(abs(means[1] - means[2]), mean - error, mean + error)
}

tlimits(cohort$age, cohort$gender)
        1                     
 3.669833 24.589853 30.570147
```